# Error when try Excel VBA code to change source of pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I came up with this code and all of my files are in a shared folder:

```vb
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivottable1").ChangePivotCache_
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase,_
SourceData:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" &_
Sheets("RawPDTBKK").Name & "!" &_
Sheets("RawPDTBKK").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Address)
```

But, it is turn out that Excel VBA does not allow me to put & "\" &. 
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The main problem, both in your original post and the edit by AAA, are the line continuation characters. They must have a space in front of them, and they can't be put everywhere.
Try without them to see if it helps. If not, edit the post again to reflect your current code

Comment: You can use the 4th parameter of `Address` and set it to `xlExternal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is one single code line, which can be shortened to this, as you are only referencing the `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivottable1").ChangePivotCache _
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RawPDTBKK").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
```